# How can you repeatedly check a folder and move any new files in the folder to another directory in Java?

Tags: java, file, directory

I'm writing a program in java and I am wondering if there is a way to repeatedly check a folder for any new files (Says every 30 seconds or so) and move any new files to another folder.

I already have working code to move the files, but I cant find anything on checking the folder for new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a `Timer`.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
List<String> list = new List();
//repeat your timer
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //loop through the folder and get the names
    File folder = new File("your/path");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        if(list.contains(listOfFiles[i].getName())
         {
             //already checked file
         }
      else
         {
             //new file add your move logic and add it to the list
             list.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
         } 
      } 
    }
  }
}, 2*60*1000, 2*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a repeated timer, you might have a look at `java.nio.file.WatchService` which enables you to be notified when files in a directory are added, modified or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Java Path Interface:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a scheduler like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) where you can create tasks that will be executed by java to achive this goal.

Anyway in my opinion it's not a very good solution. This can be much more easily done with a script. For example in linux you can create a `file_scheduler.sh` script that list the files in folder and move them in another, and with the command [crontab](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) execute this task every time you need.